# Need a smart search script: Find .php files that are less than 1 kilobyte on FTP site

Tags: php, search

I am trying to get ahead of the curve on some bad files that are repeatedly getting dumped on my hosting account through some sort of spammer method I have yet to discover.

For the short term I need to have a script that can list out any files that are in the entire directory tree that meet this criteria:

1. Is a .php file
2. Is less than 1 kilobyte in size

Optional: find, then delete all these files.

Isn't there a simple command or php script that can find all these files for me so that at least I can open them up and see if they have base64 code in them?

Is been happening for many months now... at my whits end. I have been fighting this way too long. I am going to move all the sites off the hosting and re-host them elsewhere, on a server that has the email mail() function disabled intentionally so that it's taking away the incentive to spam and hack my sites. I will use a very tricky work around to allow email to go out for those sites, but disable the normal email. It's just not a fight I can win.

Comment: What you need to do is a recursive function which scans the dir, gets the filesize and does something. Not sure if you want that all to be done remotely and over FTP.

Answer (score 3):

From the shell:

```
find . -name '*.php' -size -1k
```

To show files between 100 and 1K bytes:

```
find . -name '*.php' -size +100c -size -1k
```

Comment: almost... if I want to exclude files that are less than 100bytes how would I do that?

Comment: Add `+100c` to only match files at least 100 bytes.